# Remove comma from last item output from loop

Tags: loop, advanced-custom-fields

(or add comma to all items but the last one...)

Most of the information I have found relates to using a counter within a `foreach` loop. In this particular situation I am using Advanced Custom Fields and I am within a standard loop, not a `foreach` loop.

I need to add a comma to the end of each item except the last.

```
<?php while( has_sub_field('images') ): ?>
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'wsn_canvas'); ?>
    <?php echo $image[0]; ?>
    //echo comma here
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: `$output =  $image[0] .',';  endwhile; $output = substr_replace($output ,"",-1); echo $output;`  ?? you can also get rid of all your `php` tags .. you have no `HTML` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing 'standard' about a `while` loop and in this case it makes things harder, since you need a total count of all the items in loop in order to know if you are on the last item or not. It is not obvious how to get that total count with a function like `has_sub_field` but there is a quick way to do this that I use fairly often to build character separated strings when I don't know how many items will be in the final result.

```
$attach = array();
while( has_sub_field('images') ):
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'wsn_canvas');
    $attach[] = $image[0];
endwhile;
echo implode(', ',$attach);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `wp_sprintf_l( $pattern, $args )`:

```
$images = array();

while( has_sub_field('images') )
{
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'wsn_canvas');
    $images[] = $image[0];
}

if ( ! empty ( $images ) )
    echo wp_sprintf_l( '%l', $images );
```

This will use localized separators, an Arabic comma between the items for Arabic for example.

The separator for the last two items is by default `', and '` ([Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)), but you can change that too with a filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_sprintf_l', 'replace_oxford_comma' );

function replace_oxford_comma( $separators )
{
    $separators['between_last_two'] = ' and';
    return $separators;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to create comma separated lists with a terminal 'and' (Oxford style or not) using only CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587807/comma-delimited-lists-with-css-i-want-an-oxford-comma