# Change the last separator in the_terms

Tags: terms

How can i show `the_terms` with commas and "&" before the last one

Example:

Tags: books, review & history

I need show a "," between the terms and a "&" before the last term.

I'm using the following code to show `the_terms` in the single post:

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'post_tag', 'Tags: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
```

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/96615/73 for a built-in solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'post_tag', 'Tags: ', ', ', '');
echo preg_replace('/^(.+),([^,]+)$/', '$1 &$2', $terms);
```

Explanation for /^(.+),([^,]+)$/:

```
/     - delimiter
^     - string beginning
.+    - 1 or more characters
[^,]+ - 1 or more characters that are not a comma
$     - string end
```

$n is the nth match i.e. nth pair of brackets